# Problemas com o this.router.navigate

Tags: angular, router

Olá,
meu problema é o seguinte, preciso deixar o dinâmico sempre que jogar um valor diferente na navegação, esse é meu código:

```
editarForm() {
const valor = ('X');
this.router.navigate(['/' + valor + '/edit/'], { relativeTo: this.route });
```

}

quando lanço um "valor" qualquer nessa função o resultado é o abaixo:

```
core.js:15723 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'edit'
```

Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'edit'
    at ApplyRedirects.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.js:2469)
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (router.js:2450)
    at CatchSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/catchError.js.CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:34)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at TapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/tap.js.TapSubscriber._error (tap.js:61)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:831)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:788)
    at zone.js:892
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:17289)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:601)
    at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:502)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1744)

No front para entenderem a ideia é o seguinte:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pelo erro o problema não parece ser na variável, 2 coisas: utilize template strings para ficar mais legível o código `/${valor}/edit`, e tente colocar uma url que exista para ver se a página é carregada.

Answer (score 1):

Precisas configurar as rotas no seu módulo de rotas.

**No módulo:**

```
{
     path: 'edit/:valor',
     component: SeuComponent,
},
```

**No TS:**

```
this.router.navigate(['edit', valor], { relativeTo: this.route.parent });
```